# Get all the members details from each room

Tags: javascript, angularjs, data-structures, firebase

> With this sort of data:
>
> ```
> {
>     "rooms": {
>       "one": {
>         "name": "room alpha",
>         "type": "private"
>       },
>       "two": { ... },
>       "three": { ... }
>     },
>
>     "members": {
>       "one": {
>         "mchen": true,
>         "hmadi": true
>       },
>       "two": { ... },
>       "three": { ... }
>     },
>
>     ...
> ```
>
> How can I query all rooms with (by example)  the username of each
>   member in the room?

EDIT2:

I have tried to put players in to the games and the players are loaded with the games, that's a solution to load the related players for a game. But I only get the ID of the players, I need the username or the profile picture url by example.

[image]

You see that players is only shown by its ID because I saved it so:
    `this.root.child('games').child(gameID).child('players').child(this.currentUser.id).set(true);`

but when I get the games:

```
this.root.child('games').on('value', function(snapshot) {
   console.log(snapshot.val());
});
```

I get only the players id of course. How do I get the details of players with the games.

Comment: If you want to load all rooms with all members, I would probably simply load the entire data tree one level higher. But I get the feeling that is not what you are looking for. Can yo *edit* your question (with the edit link that's right under it) and clarify what you're trying to accomplish and what you've already tried?

Comment: i have edited the answer with more detail

Comment: Did you already try anything? If so, please post what you tried (see http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). That would also address many missing pieces of information, for example: what environment you are targeting.

Comment: edited more detail and i am using angular for web

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're looking to load the players for all games, when those games are loaded. Something like:

```
this.root.child('games').on('value', function(gamesSnapshot) {
  console.log(gamesSnapshot.val());
  var loadedPlayers = {};
  gamesSnapshot.forEach(function(gameSnapshot) {
    var game = gameSnapshot.val();
    Object.keys(game.players).forEach(function(playerId) {
      if (Object.keys(loadedPlayers).indexOf(playerId) == -1) {
        this.root.child('players').child(playerId).once(function('value', function(playerSnapshot) {
          loadedPlayers[playerId] = playerSnapshot.val();
        });
      }
    });
  });
});
```

So this code pretty much brute-force loads all the players in all the games.

Although it will likely run fine in many cases, you should always consider if it's not better to **organize your data in a way that is more in line with the needs of your application**. For example: instead of loading the entire players, you might also store the data you need to display for each player inside the games that they're part of. So if you for example need to display player names:

```
games
  -J436712379
    creator: 'ismaelaa'
    players
      simplelogin:35: 'Frank van Puffelen'
```